# Can't change more then one 1 button color with a color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, color-picker, jscolor

I have here a code that allows me to change the color from elements like a sidebar or buttons with a colorpicker.
The data is saved on localstorage.

The weird thing what happening is that this code only allows me to change the color of one of the same item. For example. On a page with 5 buttons. Only one button changes color the other ones stays at their own color. But I want to have all the 5 buttons to be changed

Here is an example i made with the html where you can see that 1 of the 3 buttons just gets a color: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLzvNO?editors=1010

```js
/*Set your own color*/
var jscolor;
var defaultColor = (localStorage.getItem("color")) ? localStorage.getItem("color"): "#0078c0";

window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
function startup() {
  jscolor = document.querySelector(".jscolor");
  if (jscolor) {
    jscolor.value = defaultColor;
    jscolor.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
    jscolor.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
    jscolor.select();
  }
  refreshSidebar(defaultColor);
}

function updateFirst(event) {
  refreshSidebar(event.target.value);
}

function refreshSidebar(color) {
  var side = document.querySelector(".themecolor");
  var text = document.querySelector(".onlyTextColor");
  var background = document.querySelector(".background");
  if (side, text, background) {
    side.style.backgroundColor = color;
    text.style.color = color;
    background.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

function updateAll(event) {
    $(".themecolor, .background,").each(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('color', event.target.value);
    if ($(this).hasClass("onlyTextColor"))
      {
          $(this).css('color', event.target.value);
      }
    else{
      $(this).css('background-color', event.target.value);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you post relevant html too?

Comment: I agree with @DanielMemije. Without the HTML this question is pretty difficult to answer as we don't know what your DOM Elements are, therefore we wont know what we are helping you to interact with, the code lists id and classes but a css class can be applied to anything and an ID doesn't define the element / object

Comment: I am sorry, here is an example i made with the html where you can see that 1 of the 3 buttons just gets a color: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLzvNO?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole issue is in your `updateAll` function.

By using `$(this)` selector you are [selecting your current HTML element](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp).

According to [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> `.each()`
>
> Type: Function( Integer **index**, Element **element** )
>
> A function to execute for each matched element.

So you can modify your `updateAll` function to match the following

```
function updateAll(event) {
  // Set color to local storage
  localStorage.setItem('color', event.target.value);
  // Loop through elements with 'themecolor' or 'background' classes
  $(".themecolor, .background").each(function(index, element){     
    // If element needs only text color change
    if($(element).hasClass("onlyTextColor")){
      // Change text color
      $(element).css('color',event.target.value)
    }
    // Else
    else{ 
      // Change background color
      $(element).css('background-color', event.target.value);
    }    
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you for letting me know about this but it still changing only 1 button color instead of all of them in the same html page

Comment: @akin it's working for me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzevPv?editors=1010

Comment: mmh yes I see you are right. Then there is something i think in my HTML what is going wrong. everytime I see only the first button that gets a color. all other buttons doesn't get the color. I used your code and see in your codepen that it does work. (Thx btw) But I don t get it, need to debug I think..